# Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected

Tags: linux, build, linker, wxwidgets

I built wxWidgets on Linux using this command:

../configure --enable-shared --disable-debug

It see results of this build:

/usr/local/lib/wx/config/gtk2-ansi-release-2.8

/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-ansi-release-2.8/wx/setup.h

wx-config output:

```
alex@alex-linux:~$ wx-config --list
    Default config is gtk2-ansi-release-2.8
  Default config will be used for output
  Alternate matches:
    gtk2-ansi-debug-2.8
    gtk2-ansi-debug-static-2.8
    gtk2-ansi-release-static-2.8
alex@alex-linux:~$ wx-config --cppflags --release
2.8
-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-ansi-release-2.8 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.8 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__
alex@alex-linux:~$ wx-config --libs --release
2.8
-L/usr/local/lib -pthread   -lwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8 -lwx_gtk2_aui-2.8 -lwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8 -lwx_gtk2_qa-2.8 -lwx_gtk2_html-2.8 -lwx_gtk2_adv-2.8 -lwx_gtk2_core-2.8 -lwx_base_xml-2.8 -lwx_base_net-2.8 -lwx_base-2.8
```

Now I am trying to build Hello wxWidgets program with Release version:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-ansi-release-2.8 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.8 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__ hello.cpp -o hello -L/usr/local/lib -pthread   -lwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8 -lwx_gtk2_aui-2.8 -lwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8 -lwx_gtk2_qa-2.8 -lwx_gtk2_html-2.8 -lwx_gtk2_adv-2.8 -lwx_gtk2_core-2.8 -lwx_base_xml-2.8 -lwx_base_net-2.8 -lwx_base-2.8
```

It compiles and runs successfully on my computer. Program dependencies:

```
ldd hello
 linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x006ef000)
 libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8.so.0 (0x00253000)
 libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.so.0 (0x005ff000)
 libwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8.so.0 (0x00110000)
 libwx_gtk2_qa-2.8.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_qa-2.8.so.0 (0x00a3c000)
 libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.so.0 (0x0019d000)
 libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.so.0 (0x00c18000)
 libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.so.0 (0x00ef8000)
 libwx_base_xml-2.8.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libwx_base_xml-2.8.so.0 (0x0047e000)
 libwx_base_net-2.8.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libwx_base_net-2.8.so.0 (0x00353000)
 libwx_base-2.8.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libwx_base-2.8.so.0 (0x006f0000)
    ...
```

Now I want to execute this program on another computer without wxWidgets installed. I copy the program and all shared libraries to another computer:

```
hello                        libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.so
libwx_base-2.8.so            libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.so.0
libwx_base-2.8.so.0          libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.so.0.6.0
libwx_base-2.8.so.0.6.0      libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.so
libwx_base_net-2.8.so        libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.so.0
libwx_base_net-2.8.so.0      libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.so.0.6.0
libwx_base_net-2.8.so.0.6.0  libwx_gtk2_qa-2.8.so
libwx_base_xml-2.8.so        libwx_gtk2_qa-2.8.so.0
libwx_base_xml-2.8.so.0      libwx_gtk2_qa-2.8.so.0.6.0
libwx_base_xml-2.8.so.0.6.0  libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8.so
libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.so        libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8.so.0
libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.so.0      libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8.so.0.6.0
libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.so.0.6.0  libwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8.so
libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.so        libwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8.so.0
libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.so.0      libwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8.so.0.6.0
libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.so.0.6.0
```

And run it:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./hello

Result:

```
Fatal Error: Mismatch between the program and library build versions detected.
The library used 2.8 (debug,ANSI,compiler with C++ ABI 1002,wx containers,compatible with 2.6),
and your program used 2.8 (no debug,ANSI,compiler with C++ ABI 1002,wx containers,compatible with 2.6).
./run.sh: line 1:  1810 Aborted                 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./hello
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to check if none of your headers declares DEBUG macro this or that way. I ran into this problem once.

Apart from that, it may be better to perform static linking instead.

Comment: No, DEBUG is not defined. This is simple Hello sample from Widgets tutorial, one small cpp file. Everything else is from the Widgets headers.

Comment: Thank you, using static wxWidgets version is working. It's OK for me now.

Comment: I strongly suggest building wxWidgets as a monolithic library if you're including all of the individual libraries. It will eliminate a lot of headaches in the long run.

Comment: How can I use "static wxWidgets"?  Do I need to compile it?